# Связь данных из двух таблиц через id

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Использую SQLite и C#.

Имеется две таблицы. В каждой из них есть уникальный ключ id.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении нового элемента в таблицу logEvents, как мне узнать, значение logPage_id?
id в обоих таблицах являются первичным ключом и увеличиваются на один при добавлении нового элемента в таблицу.

Comment: Два вопроса, как именно вы работаете с базой данных и почему в момент добавления элемента `logEvent` вы не знаете его содержимого?

Comment: @Mirdin, в базу за раз пишется журнал событий системы, а потом данные подгружаются по мере того, как пользователь скролит.
Я знаю содержимое, только хочу разобраться, нужно самому устанавливать logPage_id или есть встроенные способы сделать это автоматически?

Comment: Способы, возможно, есть. Но вы не написали, как именно работаете с базой данных, От этого очень много будет зависеть.